# Cannot read properties of undefiend (reading 'userApi') using RTKquery

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am learning a RtkQuery library with React.js. I am learning an official documintation of RtkQuery and start my learning with Quick Start Guide. I have a small database which is running on json-server.And code like this(simmilar to quick start in docs.).

**store.js**

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

import { usersApi } from "./index"


export const store = configureStore({
    reducer : {
        [usersApi.reducerPath] : usersApi.reducer,
    }, 
    middleware: (getDefMiddleware) => getDefMiddleware().concat(usersApi.middleware)
})
```

**usersApi.js**

```
import {createApi , fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react" ;


export const usersApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'usersApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001/"}),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getUsers: builder.query({
            query: () => `users`,

        })
    })
})


export const {useGetUsersQuery} = usersApi
```

**And this code in simple jsx component**

```
import {useGetUsersQuery} from "./redux"


const Loading = () => {
 return (<h1>isLoading</h1>)
}

const ShowData = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(user => {
        <li key={user.id}>{`name: ${user.name}`}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}


function App() {

  const {data , isLoading} = useGetUsersQuery()
 
  return (
    <div>
 {isLoading ? <Loading/> : <ShowData data={data}/>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**This is a text of error in browser console**

```
index.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'usersApi')
    at Module.usersApi (index.js:10:1)
    at ./src/redux/store.js (store.js:8:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/redux/index.js (index.js:10:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:15:64)
usersApi @ index.js:10
./src/redux/store.js @ store.js:8
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/redux/index.js @ index.js:10
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/App.js @ bundle.js:15
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
fn @ hot module replacement:62
./src/index.js @ App.js:30
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
```

And for more information i didn`t see nothing in redux devstools extesion.

Comment: So try `console.log(usersApi)` in `store.js` file to see what exactly is `usersApi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution: Fix your import paths

Change this line in store.js

```
import { usersApi } from "./index"
```

to this:

```
import { usersApi } from "./usersApi"
```

#### Problem: You have a dependency cycle

Your store.js file is importing from index.js.  I’m guessing that the usersApi.js and the store.js are both in the same folder. Presumably the index.js re-exports the usersApi variable so the path isn’t “wrong” in the traditional sense. But it will create a circular import!

The dependency cycle between index.js and store.js means that the contents of index.js are undefined when processing the store.js file.  The store variable depends on the contents of index.js, but the contents of index.js depend on the store variable.

Therefore the usersApi variable must be imported directly from the usersApi.js file.

Answer (score -1):

first of all i'll make changes to the store.js. It's not well configured. You've got your import mixed up. Look out for those imports.

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

import { usersApi } from "./usersApi"

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer : {
        usersApi. : usersApi.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefMiddleware) => getDefMiddleware().concat(usersApi.middleware)
})
```

secondly, I'm guessing you're getting data from user.json file not user so i'll add the .json extension to it when adding it to the userApi file.

```
import {createApi , fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react" ;

export const usersApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'usersApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: "/"}),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getUsers: builder.query({
            query: () => `users.json`,
        })
    })
})
// also you need to export the useQuery because that's what you need in your component
export const useGetUsersQuery = usersApi.endpoints.getUsers.useQuery

// if you prefer the destructure syntax
// export const { useQuery } = usersApi.endpoints.getUsers
// should be sufficient
```

lastly, useGetUserQuery doesn't have isLoading as a property so it'll always be undefined. so maybe create a function that sets the value of isloading. Also you'll need to wrap your App in a provider and pass it the value of store as a props

```
import {useGetUsersQuery} from "./userApi"
import {store} from "./store"
import {Provider} from "react-redux"

const Loading = () => {
    return (<h1>isLoading</h1>)
}

const ShowData = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(user => {
        <li key={user.id}>{`name: ${user.name}`}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}


function App() {

  const {data} = useGetUsersQuery()
  const isLoading = () => false
 
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
             {isLoading ? <Loading/> : <ShowData data={data}/>}
        </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes it’s the import path that’s the problem.  It seems like the usersApi.js and the store.js are in the same folder.  Presumably the index.js re-exports the usersApi variable so the path isn’t “wrong” in the traditional sense.  **But it will create a circular import!** The dependency cycle between index.js and store.js means that the contents of index.js are undefined when processing the store.js file.  Therefore the API must be imported directly from the usersApi.js file.

Comment: The other parts of your answer regarding the .json file extension and the isLoading property are both wrong.  I mean this politely but you should not answer things which you don’t know about.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the critic, I agree i may not have considered if data was gotten from users.js and just assumed it'll be a user.json file. However, even after changing the input statement in store.js, there's still an issue with the export from userApi because the import in the component has no access to the endpoint. I haven't used the isLoading return from the query hook prior to now, so thanks.

Comment: I’m assuming that they have a <Provider> component at the very root of their app, like where they call react-dom render().  If they didn’t have it they would get a different error message (“no store found”).  You call tell a lot about an issue by looking at the error message someone is reporting and working backwards to what would cause that error.  Where you added the <Provider> inside the App component actually won’t work because the query hook is called outside of the context of the <Provider>.

Comment: You are right, in my variation, I should call provider in a parent component, probably the root app. However their's still wouldn't work because they aren't exporting the query. So they won't have access to both isLoading or the data when it's returned. Take a look at the export in userApi.js